# Angular sending string list parameter by GET method

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular6, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Angular 6 project. And I'm sending my request to .NET Core 2.1 Web API. I'm sending string fruit list like below. But, my data coming to C# has only one item like `"'apple', 'orange', 'banana'"` . But, I want three different strings. How can I achieve this? **Please don't advice using "POST" method**

**Angular side**

```
getFruitDetails() {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('fruitType', '35');
    params = params.append('fruits', JSON.stringify(['apple', 'orange', 'banana']));

    return this.http.get('https://localhost:5000/api/Fruit/GetFruitDetails', { params: params });
}
```

**C# Side**

```
public GetFruitDetails([FromQuery] FruitModel fruitModel)
{...}

public class FruitModel
{
    public int FruitType { get; set; }
    public List<string> Fruits { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why not using `queryParams`?

Comment: What is queryparams? When I googled, every results are HttpParams. @PardeepJain

Comment: Sending parameters using `?` in url for example `https://localhost:5000/api/Fruit/GetFruitDetails/?fruit1=apple&fruit2=banana...`

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply @PardeepJain. I don't want concatting strings. So, I'm using `HttpParams`. `MarcusHöglund`' s solution is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FromQuery` attribute will add all query params that matching `fruits=value` from the querystring into the list Fruits.

Therefore, compose the params as

```
getFruitDetails() {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('fruitType', '35');
    params = params.append('fruits', 'apple');
    params = params.append('fruits', 'orange');
    params = params.append('fruits', 'banana');

    return this.http.get('https://localhost:5000/api/Fruit/GetFruitDetails', { params: params });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcusHöglund . It worked. But, Is it common way or tricky way?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir its how the FromQuery attribute work. Its the standard way :)

Comment: @D-johnAnshani why should he do that? the FromQuery attribute solves this in an elegant way. Why bring more complexity to it by manually checking it

Comment: I think your way is not correct way @D-johnAnshani . Because, strings can have comma. And then that way gave wrong result.

Comment: You don't need to pass them one by one with `params.append`, you can add the array... just don't `JSON.Stringify()` it